# Convexity of CDF and sum of conditional expectations

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, expected-value, jensen-inequality

I have a question about the relation between concavity/convexity and a sum of conditional expectations.

Especially, suppose $X$ has a CDF $F$ and pdf $f$ with support $[0,1]$. Will concavity/convexity of $F$ decides the direction of the below inequality?
$$x+\mathbb E[X]\geq\mathbb E[X|X>x]+\mathbb E[X|X\leq x],~\forall x\in(0,1)$$ or
$$x+\mathbb E[X]\leq\mathbb E[X|X>x]+\mathbb E[X|X\leq x],~\forall x\in(0,1).$$

Here, by convexity/concavity of $F$, I mean $f'(x)\geq0$ or $f'(x)\leq 0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

I have tried $F(x)=x^a,~a>0$

And found the below inequality holds for $a<1$, whereas the above inequality is true for $a>1$. and equality holds for $a=1$.

Are there any connection between convex/concave $F$ and the above relation?

or, equivalently, can we show the sign of 
$$x-\big(F(x)\mathbb E[X|X>x]+(1-F(x))\mathbb E[X|X<x]\big)$$
depends on convexity of $F$?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb{E}[X \mid X > x] + \mathbb{E}[X \mid X \leq X] = \mathbb{E}[X \cdot \mathbb{1}[X > x]] + \mathbb{E}[X \cdot \mathbb{1}[X \leq x]]$ $= \mathbb{E}[X \cdot (\mathbb{1}[X > x] + \mathbb{1}[X \leq x])] = \mathbb{E}[X]$, where $\mathbb{1}[\cdot]$ is the indicator function?

Comment: @madnessweasley no that is not true, since $\mathbb{E}[X \mid X \leq X] = \mathbb{E}[X \cdot \mathbb{1}[X \leq x]] / P(X \leq x)$

Comment: $F(x)=x^a$ does not satisfy the support condition. If the support is $[0,1]$, then filling in $x=1$ shows that the second inequality cannot hold.

Comment: Thanks @LinAlg, but I don't get your point. if $x=1$, the second inequality holds with equality because $x=1=\mathbb E[X|X\geq 1]$, isn't it?

Comment: A convex bounded function has to be constant, your question does not make sense.

Comment: @GabrielRomon I read the question as $F$ being convex or concave on $[0,1]$, but agree that it should be clarified

Comment: @GabrielRomon Romon, I've edited the question. By the convexity, I meant the positive second derivative of $F$.